# Convolution filter 2D

Tags: c++, opencv, math, image-processing, signal-processing

I'm trying to create in C++ a convolution filter for an image.
I'm using OpenCV library to manipulate my image.

But my filter doesn't work properly.

First attempt:

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;


/*
  filtre de convolution
*/

void filterConvolutionBlack(String pathImage, std::vector<std::vector<int>> filter) {
   Mat src;
   int ii = 0, jj = 0, value = 0;

   // Image source
   src = imread(pathImage, IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);

   // Image destination
   Mat dest;
   dest = src.clone();

   // On cherche le centre de la matrice
   int filterCenterX = (int)filter[0].size() / 2; // Colonne
   int filterCenterY = (int)filter.size() / 2; // Ligne

   // On parcours les lignes de l'image
   for (int i = 0; i < src.rows; ++i) {
       // On parcours les colonnes de l'image
       for (int j = 0; j < src.cols; ++j) {
           value = 0;
           // On parcours les lignes du filtre
           for (int fi = 0; fi < (int)filter.size(); ++fi) {
               // On parcours les colonnes du filtre
               for (int fj = 0; fj < (int)filter[0].size(); ++fj) {
                   // On calcul la position du pixel à modifier
                   ii = i + (fi - filterCenterY);
                   jj = j + (fj - filterCenterX);

                   // On vérifie que les postions ne sont pas hors limite
                   if (ii >= 0 && ii < src.rows && jj >= 0 && jj < src.cols) 
                   {
                       value += (int)src.at<uchar>(ii, jj) * filter[fi][fj];
                   }
               }
           }
           dest.at<uchar>(i, j) = value;
       }
   }
   imshow("Filter", dest);
 }

 int main(int argc, char **argv)
 {
   String pathImage = "loutre.png";

   // On creer un filtre 3*3
   std::vector<std::vector<int>> filter;
   filter.resize(3, std::vector<int>(3, 0));
   filter = {
       {1,1,1},
       {1,-8,1},
       {1,1,1}
   };

   filterConvolutionBlack(pathImage, filter);

   waitKey(0);

   return EXIT_SUCCESS;
 }
```

The dest variable is a final result and the src variable is the base image.

The currently result:

[image: Result]

However, the expected result is:

[image: expected].

I think that the problem comes from the array index, but I'm not sure.

Comment: You should check that `value` is within range (and limit it if necessary) before storing it to `dest`. (It also looks like your filter may not be normalized, so you may also need to scale `value` accordingly ?)

Comment: thank you paul. Effectively, by checking if the value is within the range, the result is much better :) But, i don't see how to scale the value.

Comment: Hi paul,I set a value if I exceed the range ( 0 if < 0 and 255 if >255). the result is again much better :)

Comment: Calculate the gain of your filter kernel and if it’s > 1 then divide `value` by this figure to compensate.